# A question regarding an analogue of the Kleene $T$-predicate for Koepke's ordinal computability

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, mathematical-philosophy, ordinal-computability

Does Koepke's notion of ordinal computability admit an analogue of the Kleene $T$-predicate?  If so, is the existence of such a $T$-predicate independent of $ZFC$?  Also, if one assumes the existence of such a $T$-predicate, can an analogue of the Kleene hierarchy be defined for Koepke's ordinal computability, and can one define a set theory based on that analogue of the Kleene hierarchy rather than, say, the cumulative hierarchy?

Comment: You might consider adding a top-level tag in order to make more people see this question.

Comment: @StefanKohl:  How does one add a top-level tag?

Comment: Emil Jerabek already added one in the meantime. -- Top-level tags ("arXiv tags") are those which start with two letters followed by a dot.

Comment: @StefanKohl: Since I have never heard of such a tag (and I couldn't find  such a tag in the list of tags, what does such a tag signify?

Comment: These tags describe the broad area(s) of mathematics a question belongs to. The other tags are in general for finer specification. Often people look for questions with the top-level tags for the areas they are interested in, and if a question has none, it easily gets overlooked by people who might know an answer.

Comment: @StefanKohl and@EmilJerabek:  Thanks for doing that.  Much appreciated.

Comment: See the "faq" on tagging http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow